# SpriteKit (Swift 2.1) Auto-layout programmatically?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

While SpriteKit makes developing 2D games pretty simple, one thing that annoys me is the way that I must code my game to make it resize itself on different sized iOS devices.

For example:

```
`if size.height == 568 {
//iPhone 5/5S screen dimensions
spriteNode!.size = CGSize(height: 30, width: 45)
spriteNode!.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
} else if size.height == 1024 {
//iPad screen dimensions
spriteNode!.size = CGSize(height: 60, width: 90) /* Twice the normal size */
spriteNode!.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 80) /* Moved over and above a bit */
}
`
```

As seen in the example, if the screen has a height of 768 (like the iPhone 5, which is `768x320`), different lines of code are run than if the screen has a height of 1024 (iPad).

However, this takes forever in even a simple game and would be very unfeasible for a more complex 2D platformer (such as Super Mario Bros.) is there a faster way that I can resize and reposition SpriteKit nodes for different sized iDevices (in Swift 2.1)?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the position and size of your sprites based on the height and width of your screen. For example:

```
spriteNode!.size = CGSize(height: size.height * 0.1, width: size.height * 0.1)
spriteNode!.position = CGPoint(x: size.height * 0.5, width: size.width * 0.5)
```

would  create a sprite one tenth the dimensions of your screen, in the middle of it. The sprite would stretch to fit regardless of the device, and would be put in the middle of the screen regardless of the device.